# how to sort a tuple with lambda

Tags: python, sorting, lambda

I have a tuple coords:

```
[(1, 2), (3, 2), (1, 4)]
```

And I have also a single coord: `(8, 7)`

Now I need to sort the tuple above according to the distance between each point in the tuple and the single point.

How to do this with `sorted()`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Essentially you can compute the euclidean distance between your point `pt` and each of the tuples in your list. The function [`numpy.hypot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hypot.html) can do this, although it would be trivial to implement yourself if you wanted to.

```
>>> from numpy import hypot
>>> l = [(1, 2), (3, 2), (1, 4)]
>>> pt = [8,7]
>>> sorted(l, key = lambda i: hypot(i[0]-pt[0], i[1]-pt[1]))
[(3, 2), (1, 4), (1, 2)]
```

Comment: You can (ab)use the `complex` type to avoid any other import. `sorted(l, key=lambda x: abs(complex(*x) - complex(*pt))`.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use numpy and want to get it done with pure Python,

```
>>> array = [(1, 2), (3, 2), (1, 4)]
>>> point = [8, 7]
>>> array.sort(key = lambda k: (k[0] - point[0])**2 + (k[1] - point[1])**2)
>>> array
[(3, 2), (1, 4), (1, 2)]
```